# Eclipse PDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

i downloaded eclipse pdt, seem it only support php project ??, can made it support php and java either? i dont want install 2 separate version

thanks.

Comment: I'm not trying to be mean but you need to work on your English grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You can install Eclipse for [Java Developers version](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/ganymede/SR2/eclipse-java-ganymede-SR2-macosx-carbon.tar.gz) (Mac OS Version) and then use "Software Install..." option inside Eclipse to install PDT using [these three locations](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/ganymede/SR2/eclipse-java-ganymede-SR2-macosx-carbon.tar.gz) (again, for Mac OS). Choose your platform by going to the base site.

Comment: my problem is i installed PDT version, now i want to add java dev version

Answer (score 0):

Help | Software Updates | Available Software tab

Select Ganymede Update Site or Eclipse Project Updates site (you can add others)

All sorts of available plugins and addons will be listed to support all manner of programming projects